# How do I reference a text document for point values in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network

I'm following along with Siraj Raval's video series on how to make a Neural Network (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2-dafEMk2A7YdKv4XfKpfbTH5z6rEEj3) and I'm having a lot of trouble getting my program to actually get the data values from a text document I've created. I was wondering if may be I was missing a dependency or calling it improperly

Here's the error I'm getting in Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\Liam\Desktop>py NeuralNets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NeuralNets.py", line 7, in <module>
    x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2053, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2097, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1230, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['Brain'] not in index"
```

and here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data
dataframe = pd.read_fwf('brain_body.txt')
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

# train model on data
body_reg = linear+model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)

# visualize results
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
plt.plot(x_values, body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

Please take into account that I'm a total n00b so I'm sorry if the answer to this problem is really obvious. Any and all help and suggestions accepted, thanks!

Comment: Try using `dataframe['Brain']`.

Comment: @vendaTrout good suggestion, but it led to more even more errors. Different ones I think, but more of them.

Comment: Share them, you can edit your answer and paste it.

Comment: As it turns out I was formatting my text file improperly, after some modification of the file I was able to properly run the code, thanks for your help @vendaTrout!

Comment: I have the same problem, can you explain how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I've almost got the solution. The following code does everything except print the linear regression plot (which is just missing for some reason- if anyone could answer that would be great!)

I had to do a lot of parsing of the text file, as the first ten rows were gibberish, hence "skiprows = 10", possibly because it's an .rtf, not a .txt on a Mac.

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

datafram = pd.read_fwf('/Users/sarahhernandez/Desktop/body_brain.rtf', delim_whitespace = True, names = ["Brain", "Body"] , usecols = ["Brain", "Body"], skiprows = 10)

# Only used one bracket to extract data
x = datafram['Brain']
y = datafram['Body']

# When trying to plot, I got a deprecation warning, fixed by reshaping
x.values.reshape(1,-1)
y.values.reshape(1,-1)

# Converted to list and removed last value in for x and y which were "}" and NAN, respectively
xlist = list(x)
ylist = list(y)
xlist.pop()
ylist.pop()

#Reshape lists yet again through numpy
xvec = np.array(xlist).reshape(1,-1)
xvec = xvec.astype(np.float)
yvec = np.array(ylist).reshape(1,-1)

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(xvec, yvec)

# Plot data, I'm just getting the scatter plot though, not the linear regression line
plt.scatter(xvec,yvec)
plt.plot(xvec, body_reg.predict(xvec))
plt.show()
```